# Makefile with combinations of multiple targets and dependencies

Tags: variable, wildcards, make

I have the following file tree (for example):

```
foo/1213.csv
foo/7789.csv

far/8471.csv
far/7811.csv

boo/8109.csv

bar/2778.csv
bar/3334.csv
bar/1337.csv
```

Now, I want for each `foo far boo bar` directory to create a `qux.json` inside of it, which is dependant on all of `*.csv` files in that directory.

So far, it shouldn't be to difficult - I believe something like this would work (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
%/qux.json: %/*.csv
    my-script.py -o $@ $^
```

The point where I get stuck is when there are few "classes" of rules and for each class have a different recipe, for example something like:

```
CLASS1=foo far
CLASS2=boo bar

$(patsubst %,%/qux.json,$(CLASS1)): $(patsubst %,%/*.csv,$(CLASS1))
    my-script1.py -o $@ $^

$(patsubst %,%/qux.json,$(CLASS2)): $(patsubst %,%/*.csv,$(CLASS2))
    my-script2.py -o $@ $^
```

But running `make foo/qux.json` fails with `make: *** No rule to make target 'far/*.csv', needed by 'foo/qux.json'.  Stop.`.

I tried many different things, like:

```
$(patsubst %,%/qux.json,$(CLASS1)): $(wildcard $(patsubst %/qux.json,%/*.csv,$@))
    my-script1.py -o $@ $
```

No dice.

Essentially, I have several types of subdirectories. I can enumerate each member to a makefile variable. Each subdirectory contains random number of input csv files. I want to create a json file inside each directory from all its csv files. But each class of directories needs to run a different script.

I tried reading through `man` files, I've tries searching on the internet and SO, but this s too specific for any search result and too difficult for me to figure out through manual.

Comment: `But this fails.` "Fails" _how_ exactly? Does the csv files exists before the rule is run?

Comment: I've edited the question to add a fail example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions always looked clearer to me then `%`:

```
CLASS1=foo far
CLASS2=boo bar

define f
$1/qux.json: $(wildcard $1/*.csv)
    $2
endef

$(foreach i, $(CLASS1), $(eval $(call f, $i,my-script1.py -o $$@ $$^)))
$(foreach i, $(CLASS2), $(eval $(call f, $i,my-script2.py -o $$@ $$^)))
```

But *really*, writing the following takes less time:

```
foo/qux.json: $(wildcard foo/*.csv)
     my-script1.py -o $@ $^
boo/qux.json: $(wildcard boo/*.csv)
     my-script2.py -o $@ $^
far/qux.json: $(wildcard far/*.csv)
     my-script1.py -o $@ $^
bar/qux.json: $(wildcard bar/*.csv)
     my-script2.py -o $@ $^
```

Comment: I guess this would work. However is there no other way then using defines and for each's?  Few additional questions though: what is the `eval` do here? But regarding the "unrolling" a second example, wouldn't it matter that there's a code duplication? There would be as many same rules as to how many are there in each class.

Comment: `is there no other way then using defines and for each's?` The problem is you can't use `%/qux.json: $(wildcard %/*.csv)`, because wildcard is expanded _before_ the `%` is replaced. And you can't use `$@` in rule dependencies either - it's empty. `what is the eval do here?` Parses the `target: files` stuff, I do not remember to be honest. Try without. `wouldn't it matter that there's a code duplication?` Is a question to you, I don't care for 8 lines. [Typical automation of short tasks](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/jsrtku/it_usually_takes_longer_to_write_the_automation/).